# How to use <video> tag of HTML5 in android to play Youtube videos

Tags: android, html, video, tags

I want to play youtube video in webview on click of list items.
Can anybody let me know in detail how can I use  tag of HTML5
in android.

-rajani

Answer (score 0):

Use `<iframe>` :

1. Upload the video to YouTube
2. Take a note of the video `id`
3. Define an `<iframe>` element in your web page
4. Let the `src` attribute point to the video URL
5. Use the `width` and `height` attributes to specify the dimension of the player
6. Add any other parameters to the URL (see below)

Example:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/whatever"></iframe>
```